# Cookie Details Requested

Tags: cookies

We have Wordpress 3.4 installed and looking for details regarding functionalities of cookies created by wordpress. This information is needed so that we can align with EU cookie laws. So please suggest where can I find details.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? How cookies are sent, what data are stored … anything else? What have you tried already? A full text search in the WordPress core for `setcookie` should give you a start.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see which cookies are loaded with your WordPress install, you can see it in your browser. The number of cookies differs by the number of used plugins, actions on the site, host etc.

IE for Google Chrome: rightclick on the site and choose **Inspect Element**. Click the **resources tab** and view what's in the cookies folder of the site.

Cookies starting with _utm are from Google Analytics.

Comment: To elaborate on Pieter's answer you can delete all your session cookies in the Chrome tab, click refresh on your WP site and then view the cookies, you will have to navigate around, login,  and make some comments and such to see them all show up.